# $x^p-u$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(u)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be the fraction field of the polynomial ring  over a prime finite field, $k:=\mathbb{F}_p(u)$.   how does one show the polynomial $x^p-u\in k[x]$ is  irreducible?   Probably it is easy to see that it has no root in $k$. Gauss’s lemma might let me work in the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x,u]$, but I am not sure what to do from there or if that is the right approach.

Comment: It has no root in $\mathbb{F}_p[x,u]$ because if $\alpha$ is a root (in some extension), then $(x-\alpha)^p = x^p-\alpha^p = x^p-u$, but $u$ is degree $1$ and hence cannot be a $p$th power.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "root in $F_p[x,u]$".  is it possible you mean that  $\alpha$ is an element of (some extension of) $F_p[u]$? also, and I'm sure this is a dumb question, but why must it have a root in order to factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the modified question in your comment.

If $\alpha$ is a root in some extension field, then $X^p-u=(X-\alpha)^p$ over that field. So a non-trivial factorisation in any field, $X^p-u=g(X)h(X)$ say, implies $g(X)=(X-\alpha)^r=X^r-r\alpha X^{r-1}+\dots$ with $r\ne 0, p$. If the coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_p[u]$ then $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}_p[u]$.

Comment: I think the end conclusion should be that $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_p[u]$? This suffices, of course :-)

Comment: Thanks, @JyrkiLahtonen. Too early in the day. And this must be a duplicate question, though I haven't found it.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, it is rather likely that the question has been handled already. I could immediately locate a link to a proof for the fact that $x^p-u$ is irreducible over any field $F$ that does not contain a $p$th root of $u$ - irrespective of $\mathrm{char} F$. But your method is simpler than that I think. May be later :-)